# Rails POST throws GET error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails link that's using the POST method:

```
link_to "Run", forecast_run_path(@forecast), method: :post
```

to call a defined post route:

```
  resources :forecasts do
    post :run       
  end
```

The route appears in `rake routes` output as expected:

```
forecast_run POST   /forecasts/:forecast_id/run(.:format)                                   forecasts#run
```

And when I inspect the page, the expected post link appears in the page:

```
<a href="/forecasts/20/run" data-method="post" rel="nofollow" title="Run Forecast">Run Forecast</a>
```

In dev it works fine, and was good in production until sometime just a few days ago - I can't find any change that seems like it should have broken it. But when I click the link, I get the error `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/forecasts/20/run")`

I agree that no GET route matches, but it should be using POST.

This is Ruby 2.1.5, Rails 4.2.0

Comment: `<a>` tags cannot cause POST requests. It's up to Rails' [unobtrusive javascript](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript) to find all `<a>` tags with a `data-method` attribute, and, using JavaScript, trigger the equivalent POST requests.

Something is preventing this from happening, but we cannot say what or why with what you've given us.

Comment: This was some sort of temporary glitch. The problem went away after a few hours. I still have no idea why but if I figure it out I will update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my own embarrassment and for the benefit of anyone else who has the same issue:
As I switched among different clients, I didn't notice that on one of them NoScript in Firefox was blocking javascript on that site. Doh!

Comment: Vote up for your honesty!

Answer (score 0):

When you post a run, the form will direct you to the show action where it displays the newly posted run, in your case you don't have a show action for run, so implement a show action and should work fine.